# How do I fix 'dkpg-divert: error: mismatch on package'?

Tags: apt, nvidia, dpkg, 19.10

I am running `apt --fix-broken install`. I get:

```
dpkg-divert: error: mismatch on package when removing 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu.so.1 by libnvidia-gl-390'
found 'diversion of /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu.so.1 to /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu.so.1.distrib by nvidia-340
```

(also other stuff but let's take it one step at a time)

Aha! Thinks I; I'll remove nvidia-340 then, except ...

```
apt remove nvidia-340
...
Package 'nvidia-340' is not installed, so not removed
```

How do I remove diversion errors from packages that look to me at though they aren't installed? What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like this is a bug with Ubuntu. [package libnvidia-gl-390 (not installed) failed to install/upgrade: new libnvidia-gl-390:amd64 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2 (NOT FIXED)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1768050)

The workaround I did was #5, Yuri's improvement of Alexandre's suggestion

> Try
>
> # for FILE in $(dpkg-divert --list | grep nvidia-340 | awk '{print $3}'); do echo $FILE; done
>
> first and choose the correct number for substring `{print $3}`
>
> For example for Russian locale it will be $2:
>
> # for FILE in $(dpkg-divert --list | grep nvidia-340 | awk '{print $2}'); do dpkg-divert --remove $FILE; done

Comment: This didn't work for me, it only echo the content of the file or the do command is not recognized.

Answer (score 2):

I posted a more laborious answer to the bug report, you can find here
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-390/+bug/1768050/comments/8