# Problem with broken APT after trying to install Nvidia drivers in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, games, vulkan

I've come to the following situations, where I prefer to explain my situation and get a proper set of steps/actions to make it work properly.

Info for my laptop:

```
System:    Host: zutobg-Latitude-E6220 Kernel: 4.15.0-101-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: LENOVO product: 42844MG v: ThinkPad W520 serial: N/A
           Mobo: LENOVO model: 42844MG serial: N/A UEFI [Legacy]: LENOVO v: 8BET62WW (1.42 ) date: 07/26/2013
Battery    BAT0: charge: 60.8 Wh 100.0% condition: 60.8/56.2 Wh (108%)
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-2860QM (-MT-MCP-) cache: 8192 KB
           clock speeds: max: 3600 MHz 1: 797 MHz 2: 799 MHz 3: 797 MHz 4: 796 MHz 5: 797 MHz 6: 797 MHz
           7: 797 MHz 8: 798 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
           Card-2: NVIDIA GF106GLM [Quadro 2000M]
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.6 ) drivers: modesetting,nvidia (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel Sandybridge Mobile version: 3.3 Mesa 19.2.8
Audio:     Card-1 NVIDIA GF106 High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-2 Intel 6 Series/C200 Series Family High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-101-generic
Network:   Card-1: Intel 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) driver: e1000e
           IF: enp0s25 state: down mac: f0:de:f1:7a:da:2d
           Card-2: Intel Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 driver: iwlwifi
           IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: 24:77:03:1a:14:f8
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1506.3GB (13.8% used)
           ID-1: USB /dev/sda model: Expansion size: 1000.2GB
           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: Crucial_CT250MX2 size: 250.1GB
           ID-3: /dev/sdc model: Samsung_SSD_850 size: 256.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 44G used: 14G (33%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda6
           ID-2: /home size: 336G used: 29G (10%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda7
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 5.24GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda5
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 57.0C mobo: N/A
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: 2514
Info:      Processes: 330 Uptime: 1:10 Memory: 2769.5/32051.1MB Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.56
```

So I have card-1 and card-2. Until  recently I just used my machine for basic stuff, not playing games. I decided to explore Steam. Before that I haven't done anything in terms of VGA drivers or setup beside using [Software & Updates program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6Co3.png) to select the driver on the top. Did it work properly back in the time - I don't know and it doesn't matter anymore.

So the game I wanted to play require Vulcan 3D API which

I said to myself, OK, i have Nvidia and I have a driver, so it should be OK.

But the game didn't start because of the Vulkan 3D API error.
Then I tried to install vulkan-sdk which conclude in the [following error](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/issue/view/5cadd61fe46ffe7d52e3815e)

After that I reached a dozens pages through google to solve the issue and ofc a lot of commands happened. Here they are:

```
  357  sudo apt-get update
  358  sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
  359  uname -r
  360  steam -tcp
  361  apt install meson libsystemd-dev pkg-config ninja-build git libdbus-1-dev libinih-dev
  362  sudo apt install meson libsystemd-dev pkg-config ninja-build git libdbus-1-dev libinih-dev
  363  ls
  364  git clone https://github.com/FeralInteractive/gamemode.git
  365  cd gamemode
  366  git checkout 1.5.1
  367  ./bootstrap.sh
  368  sudo apt-get install python3 python3-pip python3-setuptools                        python3-wheel ninja-build
  369  pip3 --version
  370  nvidia-settings
  371  which nvidia-smi
  372  sudo prime-select nvidia
  373  nvidia-settings
  374  cd gamemode
  375  ./bootstrap.sh
  376  dpkg -l nvidia
  377  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
  378  sudo apt update
  379  chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.82.run
  380  ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.82.run
  381  sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-440.82.run
  382  inxi -Fxz
  383  sudo apt install inxi
  384  inxi -Fxz
  385  apt install vulcan-utils
  386  sudo apt install vulcan-utils
  387  wget -qO - http://packages.lunarg.com/lunarg-signing-key-pub.asc | sudo apt-key add -
  388  sudo wget -qO /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lunarg-vulkan-1.1.106-bionic.list http://packages.lunarg.com/vulkan/1.1.106/lunarg-vulkan-1.1.106-bionic.list
  389  sudo apt update
  390  sudo apt install vulkan-sdk
  391  sudo apt install libvulkan-dev
  392  sudo apt install vulkan-sdk
  393  sudo apt install libglm-dev cmake libxcb-dri3-0 libxcb-present0 libpciaccess0 libpng-dev libxcb-keysyms1-dev libxcb-dri3-dev libx11-dev g++ gcc g++-multilib libmirclient-dev libwayland-dev libxrandr-dev libxcb-ewmh-dev git python3 bison
  394  sudo apt install vulkan-sdk
  395  libvulkan-dev --version
  396  sudo apt install vulkan-sdk
  397  sudo apt update
  398  sudo apt install vulkan-sdk
  399  sudo apt install lunarg-vulkan-sdk
  400  nvidia-settings
  401  sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
  402  ls
  403  cd /etc/vulkan/
  404  ls
  405  cd icd.d/
  406  ls
  407  nvidia-settings
  408  ls
  409  cd Downloads/
  410  ls
  411  chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-396.18.run
  412  sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-396.18.run
  413  nvidia-settings
  414  vulkaninfo
  415  sudo apt install vulkan-utils
  416  sudo apt install vulkan-sdk
  417  vulkaninfo
  418  tar xf vulkansdk-linux-x86_64-1.2.135.0.tar.gz 
  419  ls
  420  cd Downloads/
  421  ls
  422  cd 1.2.135.0/
  423  ls
  424  source setup-env.sh 
  425  vulkaninfo
  426  vulkaninfo --html
  427  nvidia-settings
  428  vkvia
  429  sudo apt install vulkan-sdk
  430  wget -qO - http://packages.lunarg.com/lunarg-signing-key-pub.asc | sudo apt-key add -
  431  sudo wget -qO /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lunarg-vulkan-1.1.92-bionic.list http://packages.lunarg.com/vulkan/1.1.92/lunarg-vulkan-1.1.92-bionic.list
  432  sudo apt update
  433  sudo apt install vulkan-sdk
  434  libvlkan-dev --version
  435  sudo apt install glslang-tools
  436  sudo apt install vulkan-sdk
  437  sudo apt install libvulcan-dev
  438  sudo apt install aptitude
  439  sudo aptitude install lunarg-vulkan-sdk
  440  vkcube
  441  sudo apt install vulkan-sdk
  442  sudo apt install mesa-vulkan-drivers
  443  vkcube
  444  sudo apt-get install -y libvulkan-dev
  445  sudo apt install vulkan-sdk
  446  vulkaninfo
  447  nvidia-settings
  448  vulkaninfo
  449  vkcube
  450  apt install vulkan-utils
  451  sudoapt install vulkan-utils
  452  sudo apt install vulkan-utils
  453  sudo apt upgrade
  454  sudo apt install nvidia-graphics-drivers-396 nvidia-settings vulkan vulkan-utils
  455  vkcube
  456  vulkaninfo
  457  sudo apt install vulkan-sdk
  458  dnf remove xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-340xx akmod-nvidia-340xx
  459  nvidia-settings
  460  sudo apt install vulkan-sdk
  461  vulkaninfo
  462  vkcube
  463  sudo apt install vulkan-utils
  464  sudo apt-get install -y libvulkan-dev
  465  libvlkan-dev --version
  466  vulkaninfo --html
  467  export VULKAN_SDK=~/vulkan/1.1.xx.y/x86_64
  468  export PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/bin:$PATH
  469  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  470  export VULKAN_SDK=~/vulkan/1.1.xx.y/x86_64
  471  export PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/bin:$PATH
  472  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  473  export VK_LAYER_PATH=$VULKAN_SDK/etc/vulkan/explicit_layer.d
  474  nvidia-settings
  475  vulkaninfo --html
  476  vkcube
  477  vulkaninfo
  478  sudo apt install vulkan-sdk
  479  vulkaninfo
  480  vkcube
  481  nvidia-settings
  482  apt-get install -f
  483  sudo apt-get install -f
  484  sudo apt upgrade
  485  sudo apt-get install -f
  486  sudo apt update --fix-missing
  487  sudo apt install -f
  488  sudo dpkg --configure -a
  489  sudo dpkg -l | grep ^..r
  490  sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove --reinstreq
  491  sudo apt clean
  492  sudo apt update
  493  apt-get
  494  nvidia-settings
  495  apt-get install -f
  496  sudo apt-get install -f
  497  sudo apt autoremove
  498  sudo apt --fix=broken install
  499  sudo apt --fix-broken install
  500  dpkg --configure -a
  501  sudo dpkg --configure -a
  502  sudo apt update
  503  nvidia-settings
  504  lspci | grep VGA
  505  vkcube
  506  vulkaninfo
  507  inxi -Fxz
  508  lspci | grep VGA
  509  nvidia-smi
  510  modinfo
  511  vulkaninfo
  512  nvidia-settings
```

Basically i tried so many things listed above, that in the end I get a broken Nvidia driver and broken package manager because of that.

Using the command `nvidia-settings` I can reach my Nvidia driver [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzJug.png) The command `nvidia-smi` is showing [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6vVE.png)

But in order to play any game I need to switch my prime profile to be the intel one https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxMtd.png

Reboots is required.

Now ofc the commands `nvidia-smi` is producing:

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Beside of that I got a broken package manager:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVP99.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW6R9.png

If I try to install a program I got:

```
zutobg@zutobg-Latitude-E6220:~$ sudo apt-get install hardinfo
[sudo] password for zutobg: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnvidia-ifr1-390 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 but it is not going to be installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390:i386 but it is not going to be installed
 nvidia-driver-390 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390 (= 390.132-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-390:i386 (= 390.132-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

How I can fix all those added PPA, manual installed Nvidia over other driver and how to make it work.

Thank you for your help.

PS: some additional info from commands

```
zutobg@zutobg-Latitude-E6220:~$ cat /var/log/gpu-manager.log 
log_file: /var/log/gpu-manager.log
last_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
new_boot_file: /var/lib/ubuntu-drivers-common/last_gfx_boot
can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-was-loaded file
can't access /opt/amdgpu-pro/bin/amdgpu-pro-px
Looking for nvidia modules in /lib/modules/4.15.0-101-generic/updates/dkms
Found nvidia module: nvidia.ko
Looking for amdgpu modules in /lib/modules/4.15.0-101-generic/updates/dkms
Is nvidia loaded? no
Was nvidia unloaded? no
Is nvidia blacklisted? yes
Is intel loaded? yes
Is radeon loaded? no
Is radeon blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu loaded? no
Is amdgpu blacklisted? no
Is amdgpu versioned? no
Is amdgpu pro stack? no
Is nouveau loaded? no
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Is nvidia kernel module available? yes
Is amdgpu kernel module available? no
Vendor/Device Id: 8086:126
BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
Is boot vga? yes
Vendor/Device Id: 10de:dda
BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
Is boot vga? no
Error: can't access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/driver
The device is not bound to any driver.
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
Found "/dev/dri/card0", driven by "i915"
output 0:
    card0-LVDS-1
Number of connected outputs for /dev/dri/card0: 1
Does it require offloading? yes
last cards number = 2
Has amd? no
Has intel? yes
Has nvidia? yes
How many cards? 2
Has the system changed? No
Intel IGP detected
Intel hybrid system
Removing /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-nvidia-prime.conf
Setting power control to "auto" in /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control
```

---

```
zutobg@zutobg-Latitude-E6220:~$ uname -a
Linux zutobg-Latitude-E6220 4.15.0-101-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 11 10:07:26 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

```
zutobg@zutobg-Latitude-E6220:~$ lspci -nnk |egrep -A3 -i "3D|VGA"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0126] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [17aa:21d1]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GF106GLM [Quadro 2000M] [10de:0dda] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GF106GLM [Quadro 2000M] [17aa:21d1]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GF106 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:0be9] (rev a1)
```

---

```
zutobg@zutobg-Latitude-E6220:~$ sudo lshw -C display
[sudo] password for zutobg: 
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GF106GLM [Quadro 2000M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:ffffffff0-fffffffef iomemory:ffffffff0-fffffffef memory:f0000000-f1ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d3ffffff ioport:5000(size=128) memory:f2080000-f20fffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:38 memory:f2400000-f27fffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:6000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

---

```
zutobg@zutobg-Latitude-E6220:~$ dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia
ii  bbswitch-dkms                                 0.8-4ubuntu1                                     amd64        Interface for toggling the power on NVIDIA Optimus video cards
ii  bumblebee                                     3.2.1-17                                         amd64        NVIDIA Optimus support for Linux
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-390:amd64                      390.132-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-390                          390.132-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-390:amd64                   390.132-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-390:i386                    390.132-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-390:amd64                    390.132-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-390:i386                     390.132-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-390:amd64                    390.132-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-390:i386                     390.132-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-390:amd64                      390.132-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-390:i386                       390.132-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
iU  libnvidia-ifr1-390:amd64                      390.132-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
iU  libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386                       390.132-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-390                      390.132-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-390                               390.132-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
iU  nvidia-driver-390                             390.132-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-390                      390.132-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-390                      390.132-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
rc  nvidia-opencl-icd-340                         340.108-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA OpenCL ICD
ii  nvidia-prime                                  0.8.8.2                                          all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                               440.64-0ubuntu0~0.18.04.1                        amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-390                              390.132-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  primus                                        0~20150328-6                                     amd64        client-side GPU offloading for NVIDIA Optimus
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390                 390.132-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Comment: I think you need to download and install one of the [Nvidia Vulkan Drivers](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/) . I'm not sure if the repo version has the Vulkan capability. And also your GPU is in the list of [Legacy GPUs](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/legacy-gpu/) so you  have to avoid downloading the 440 and 435 versions.

Comment: Yes, actually one of the things I did was exactly that. The tings is first I need to fix my broken package manager, then purge all the driver mess in order to have a clean ground for me to then install the proper driver.

Comment: @ParsaMousavi you can see from my terminal history number 379 and number 411 that I tried to did that, the first one got through, the second didn't as it is not for my VGA. Also during this processes I realised  my card doesn't support Vulkan, But now I want to fix all of that before applying the proper driver. It got too messed up IMO. Now I can only use the other video card. Games didn't start when Nvidia is selected.

Comment: So perhaps your intel GPU supports vulkan better that your Nvidia GPU.

Comment: Maybe yes, but how I can make the Nvidia to be working properly now, because in its current state it is unusable, OpenGL games can't start on my Nvidia, as something is wrong. Can you suggest how I can fix my package manager and properly purge the current Nvidia stuff? Thx

Comment: Can you run " sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-390" ?

Comment: zutobg@zutobg-Latitude-E6220:~$ sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-390  
[sudo] password for zutobg:   
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.  
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
 libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-390:i386 but it is not going to be installed  
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: I think you have to install the 32-bit versions of them too . Try "sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 ; sudo apt update ; sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-390:i386" . Personally after I was installed steam , I needed to install the 32-bit OpenGL libraries to make the steam work.

Comment: OK, but my apt is still broken and I don't know how to fix it.  [The suggested "apt --fix-broken install" doesn't help](https://pastebin.com/edyiJ00z)

Comment: If you want to start again from the beginning , try "sudo apt-get remove libnvidia* nvidia* --purge " and re-install only drivers and libraries for the 390 driver.

Comment: Cool, but to said once more [my package is broken and I don't know how to fix it](https://pastebin.com/z9fyJTpj)

Comment: Also there's another [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209200/how-do-i-fix-dkpg-divert-error-mismatch-on-package) which is centered around the same problem.

Comment: I've reviewed all of your pastebins and I think the only way to get rid of that is by entirely deleting the libnvidia-ifr1-390:i386 package. I've came across the "unmet-dependencies" problem with apt many times in the past.

Comment: [Here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/debian-linux/ubuntu-linux-rollback-an-apt-get-upgrade/) is a way to rollback your software installations via apt if you encountered such a situation in the future.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but still nothing helps me to fix the apt. I can't remove, purge, clean or whatever, I'll keep researching. I edited the title to represent my current actual problem.

Comment: I think the method 2 and 5 [here](https://appuals.com/fix-unmet-dependencies-error-ubuntu/) might help you to fix the unmet dependencies error.

Comment: Thank you all for the help, I solve my APT dpkg-divert: error with the following command  "dpkg-divert --list|LC_ALL=C awk '$NF=="nvidia-340",$0=$3'|xargs -L1 sudo dpkg-divert --remove"  
after that I did "sudo apt upgrade" and "sudo apt --fix-broken install"  seen and modified from @ParsaMousavi suggested [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209200/how-do-i-fix-dkpg-divert-error-mismatch-on-package) and help from linuxquestions forum. I'll see now what i can do for my Nvidia driver